# Syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting '('

Tags: ruby, arrays

Using the following line of code I'm trying to insert a tuple into the `@test_results` array of the `@test_object`:

```
@test_object.@test_results << [@u, @m, @r, @p]
```

But it raise the following error:

```
unexpected tIVAR, expecting '(' (SyntaxError)
```

Why is Ruby expecting '('?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is, why do you type `.@test_results`? It's not the proper way to access object's instance variable from outside of the object. That's why you have this error.

You probably should have accessor in class that `@test_object` belongs to:

```
attr_accessor :test_results
```

or just a reader, if you don't need `test_results=` method:

```
attr_reader :test_results
```

The former is the equivalent of:

```
def test_results
  @test_results
end

def test_results=(value)
  @test_results = value
end
```

The latter is the equivalent of:

```
def test_results
  @test_results
end
```

Then, you can simply type:

```
@test_object.test_results << [@u, @m, @r, @p]
```

Comment: I put the '@' since I got an error otherwise, but I totally forgot the attr_accessor in the test object's class, and I was assuming I had one.