# Trying to move cards into player hand

Tags: ruby, loops, variables, methods, block

I created the deck, shuffled the cards, and now trying to deal 7 cards into the hands of 4 players.

Getting the following error:

```
irb(main):097:0*      deck.each do
irb(main):098:1*       Player.@hand << deck.pop()
irb(main):099:1>     end
SyntaxError: (irb):98: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting '('
      Player.@hand << deck.pop()
              ^
```

With this code:

```
class Player 
  attr_accessor :hand 

  def initialize(hand) 
    @hand = hand 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Can you add the Player class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting '('](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625992/syntax-error-unexpected-tivar-expecting)

Comment: You should not be using `.@hand` to access the class variable. See my link above

Comment: @Royal you need some form of function to manipulate the class variable. David's answer should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a method on the Player to accept a new card, adding it their hand.

So something like:

```
def take_card(card)
  hand << card
end
```

... leading to ...

```
deck.each do
  @player.take_card deck.pop
end
```

Note the @player, which I'm using to reference an instance of the Player class. Using Player is probably not correct here.

You could implement an operator ..

```
def <<(card)
  hand << card
end
```

... and then ...

```
deck.each do
  @player << deck.pop
end
```

Comment: @davidaldrige Like this: Player.take_card << deck.pop  I noticed there was no assignment operator?

Comment: No assignment operator needed, but I posted an update using one.

Comment: This was the result: irb(main):100:0*      deck.each do
irb(main):101:1*       Player.take_card << deck.pop
irb(main):102:1>     end
NoMethodError: undefined method `take_card' for Player:Class
        from (irb):101:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):100:in `each'
        from (irb):100
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'

Comment: You need to initialise an instance of the class ... `@player = Player.new`, and then `@player.take_card deck.pop`

Comment: @Royal Please do not post code in comments. That should all go into your question.